# Least square estimator for regression with errors depending on observed values

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, stata

Consider the following model: $y_i = \beta x_i + \epsilon_i x_i$ where $y_i$, i = 1,2,3...n are observed; $x_i$, i = 1,2...n are known positive constants and $\beta$ is an unknown parameter. There errors $\epsilon_1$, $\epsilon_2$,...$\epsilon_n$ are independent and identically distributed random variables have probability density function
$f(u) = \frac{1}{2\lambda}e^{-\frac{|u|}{\lambda}}$ and $\lambda$ is an unknown parameter.

1. Find the least squares estimator for $\beta$
2. Find the maximum likelihood estimator of $\beta$

I could do second part but not the first one. How do we define least squares for this model? Is this same as  minimising $\Sigma_{i=1}^{n} \epsilon_i^2$ ?

Comment: Hint: $\frac{y_i}{x_i} = \frac{\beta x_i}{x_i} + \frac{\epsilon_i x_i}{x_i}$

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag and read its wiki!

Comment: Then should I try to minimise sum of $\epsilon^2_i$ ?